ValueError: dtype='string' is not a valid dtype for Keras type promotion
When I train my model in a custom training loop I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/backend/common/dtypes.py", line 141, in _least_upper_bound
    bounds = [UB[n] for n in N]
              ~~^^^
KeyError: 'string'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/easwar/Downloads/hybridmodel/pytorch/transformer_decoder/model.py", line 3, in <module>
    from transformer import ChessTransformer
  File "/Users/easwar/Downloads/hybridmodel/pytorch/transformer_decoder/transformer.py", line 208, in <module>
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_weights))
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/base_optimizer.py", line 291, in apply_gradients
    self.apply(grads, trainable_variables)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/base_optimizer.py", line 356, in apply
    self._backend_apply_gradients(grads, trainable_variables)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/base_optimizer.py", line 419, in _backend_apply_gradients
    self._backend_update_step(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/optimizer.py", line 121, in _backend_update_step
    tf.__internal__.distribute.interim.maybe_merge_call(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/merge_call_interim.py", line 51, in maybe_merge_call
    return fn(strategy, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/optimizer.py", line 135, in _distributed_tf_update_step
    distribution.extended.update(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 3005, in update
    return self._update(var, fn, args, kwargs, group)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 4075, in _update
    return self._update_non_slot(var, fn, (var,) + tuple(args), kwargs, group)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 4081, in _update_non_slot
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 596, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/optimizer.py", line 132, in apply_grad_to_update_var
    return self.update_step(grad, var, learning_rate)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/adam.py", line 148, in update_step
    ops.multiply(m, alpha), ops.add(ops.sqrt(v), self.epsilon)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/ops/numpy.py", line 168, in add
    return backend.numpy.add(x1, x2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/sparse.py", line 493, in sparse_wrapper
    return func(x1, x2)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/numpy.py", line 32, in add
    dtype = dtypes.result_type(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/backend/common/dtypes.py", line 309, in result_type
    return _lattice_result_type(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/backend/common/dtypes.py", line 260, in _lattice_result_type
    out_dtype = _least_upper_bound(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/backend/common/dtypes.py", line 144, in _least_upper_bound
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: dtype='string' is not a valid dtype for Keras type promotion.

this is most likely because the trainable weights are in a string format for some reason that I can't figure out, this is what the dtypes of the trainable weights array looks like: Trainable variables dtypes: ['float32', 'float32', 'float32', 'float32', 'float32', 'float32'...]
clearly they are all strings, in comparison this is what the gradients array looks like (the dtypes):
gradient variables dtypes: [tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, ...]
This is the code that I used to train my model, the custom training loop is at the bottom,I get the error from this line of code: optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_weights))
This is the full code:
import tensorflow as tf
import math
import argparse
import yaml
from loss import LabelSmoothedCE

from modules import BoardEncoder, MoveDecoder
from pgn_parser import dataset, val_dataset, batch_size
from lr_schedule import get_lr
from utils import topk_accuracy

class ChessTransformer(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, cfg):
        super(ChessTransformer, self).__init__()

        self.code = "ED"

        self.vocab_sizes = cfg['model']['vocab_sizes']
        self.n_moves = cfg['model']['n_moves']
        self.d_model = cfg['model']['d_model']
        self.n_heads = cfg['model']['n_heads']
        self.d_queries = cfg['model']['d_queries']
        self.d_values = cfg['model']['d_values']
        self.d_inner = cfg['model']['d_inner']
        self.n_layers = cfg['model']['n_layers']
        self.dropout = cfg['model']['dropout']

        # Encoder
        self.board_encoder = BoardEncoder(
            vocab_sizes=self.vocab_sizes,
            d_model=self.d_model,
            n_heads=self.n_heads,
            d_queries=self.d_queries,
            d_values=self.d_values,
            d_inner=self.d_inner,
            n_layers=self.n_layers,
            dropout=self.dropout,
        )

        # Decoder
        self.move_decoder = MoveDecoder(
            vocab_size=self.vocab_sizes["moves"],
            n_moves=self.n_moves,
            d_model=self.d_model,
            n_heads=self.n_heads,
            d_queries=self.d_queries,
            d_values=self.d_values,
            d_inner=self.d_inner,
            n_layers=self.n_layers,
            dropout=self.dropout,
        )

        # Initialize weights
        self.init_weights()

    def init_weights(self):
        """
        Initialize weights in the transformer model.
        """
        # Glorot uniform initialization
        for layer in self.layers:
            for weight in layer.weights:
                if len(weight.shape) > 1:  # Check for at least two dimensions
                    initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform()
                    weight.assign(initializer(weight.shape))
    def call(self, inputs):
        # Encoder
        boards = self.board_encoder(
            inputs["turns"],
            inputs["white_kingside_castling_rights"],
            inputs["white_queenside_castling_rights"],
            inputs["black_kingside_castling_rights"],
            inputs["black_queenside_castling_rights"],
            inputs["board_positions"],
        )  # (N, BOARD_STATUS_LENGTH, d_model)

        # Decoder
        moves = self.move_decoder(
            inputs["encoded_moves"][:, :-1], inputs["lengths"], boards
        )  # (N, n_moves, move_vocab_size)
        # Note: We don't pass the last move as it has no next-move

        return moves
    
with open('config.yaml', 'r') as file:
        cfg = yaml.safe_load(file)
model = ChessTransformer(cfg)
criterion = LabelSmoothedCE(eps=cfg['training']['label_smoothing'],
                       n_predictions=cfg['training']['n_moves'])

LR = get_lr(
    step=cfg['training']['step'],
    d_model=cfg['model']['d_model'],
    warmup_steps=cfg['training']['warmup_steps'],
    schedule=cfg['training']['lr_schedule'],
    decay=cfg['training']['lr_decay'],
) 
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
    learning_rate=LR,
    beta_1=cfg['training']['betas'][0],  
    beta_2=cfg['training']['betas'][1],  
    epsilon=cfg['training']['epsilon']
)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=criterion)


print("start of epoch 1")
for i, batch in enumerate(dataset):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        batch = batch[0]
        predicted_moves = model(batch)  # (N, n_moves, move_vocab_size)

        # Loss
        loss = criterion(
            y_true=batch,#batch["encoded_moves"][:, 1:],  # (N, n_moves)
            y_pred=predicted_moves,  # (N, n_moves, move_vocab_size)
            #lengths=batch["lengths"],  # (N, 1)
        )
        
        loss = loss / batch_size   
    
    print(i)
    

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_weights)

    print(f"Trainable variables dtypes: {[var.dtype for var in model.trainable_weights]}")
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_weights))

    top1_accuracy, top3_accuracy, top5_accuracy = topk_accuracy(
                logits=predicted_moves[:, 0, :],  # (N, move_vocab_size)
                targets=batch["encoded_moves"][:, 1],  # (N)
                k=[1, 3, 5],
            )
    

